# How Can I Connect to Kubernetes Pod Network?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, vpn, sdn

I have a bare metal kubernetes cluster.I would like to reach pod network (i use calico-canal) with vpn and be able to communicate with my pods directly(e.g from browser).
I am trying to use Pritunl VPN.
I can connect the VPN with client but i can not reach anything inside the cluster.(except own ip)
I tried those cdr's to client but result is the same:

```
10.244.0.0/16
10.244.0.0/24
10.245.0.0/16
10.244.1.0/24
```

Note: My internal pod network cidr is : 10.244.0.0/16 and my nodes(host machine) cidr is 192.168.8.0/24

How can i connect inside pod network and reach my services directly from vpn client ?

Note2: I use vpn hostNetwork: true mode because it uses dynamic ports when client is connected.

Comment: Have you exposed your pods with a service?

Comment: No.I know i can expose my pods.But i want to connect pod network for experimental purposes.

Comment: the case you want could be resolved via Calico + dynamic routing deamon (like OSPF or BGP) to announce routes to Pod network CIDRs dynamically (for each node respectively), but it is too complicated. You can start from here https://cloudnativelabs.github.io/post/2017-05-22-kube-pod-networking/

Answer (score 0):

In Kuberentes the Pod networking should ensure other Pods could communicate to each other. That's basically it. It was not designed to allow serving incoming requests out of the box. As you may see the Pod's IP range `10.244.0.0/16` is a private one i.e. is not routable over the Internet.

As already mentioned the correct approach is to expose your pods using Services. While you are on bare metal cluster the NodePort type could be a quick way to go
(assuming you have `kubectl` connectivity to your cluster through `vpn`):

```
kubectl expose po <your-pod-name> --port=<port> --type=NodePort --name=MyService
```

Another option might be to run something like `busybox` pod with built-in `wget` tool to access inter-pod network within the cluster.

```
kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh
# wget <your-pod-ip>
```

Of course the preferred way for production-grade cluster should be something like Ingress pointing to your Service-backed Pods supported by appropriate Ingress Controller. Again while you are on bare metal and don't have LoadBalancer service out-of-the box like in most clouds, you Ingress Controller might do the load balancing job as well.

Comment: Thanks for answer.I know i should use service,ingress etc. But i want to connect pod network for test and experimental purposes.So i do not want to reach my service i just want to connect pod network.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to reach pod network (i use calico-canal) with vpn and be able to communicate with my pods directly(e.g from browser).

This is not possible if you don't expose the `pod`. You need a `service` that will expose the `pod`, later you may use that servers in `ingress` so you are able to connect to if from the browser.

> How can i connect inside pod network and reach my services directly from vpn client ?

I would setup a `pod` and expose it via `service`. Later I would use this service as a gateway to access other pods.

I would recommend you go over the documentation for [Cluster Networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/), it explains how the model works and it's briefly talking about number of CNI's. Maybe you will find something that will be more helpful.

Comment: I want t connect pod network for experimental purposes.I created a vpn pod.I can connect that pod but i cannot ping other pods.

Comment: As mentioned by @Crou, that's not how it works. to get access to your pods you have to expose it via `service` and than later a `ingress`.